# How can I find out the source of arp request if it is in another subnet?

Tags: wireshark, arp

Our subnet is connected with other subnets with router.
Using wireshark I see some arp requests coming to ip addresses of our subnet from the router.
Such as

> Broadcast ARP 60  Who has
>   10.162.3.172?  Tell 10.162.0.1

Where 10.162.0.1 is the router.
I want to determine the source computer from other subnet, which sends this requests. How can I perform it?

**UPD** subnet is 10.162.0.3.172/24
But if ARP never crosses broadcast domain boundaries then how computers from other networks can know destination of the packets(destination physical address) ? Is it obtained from the arp-table of the router? And why could router send arp requests, except probing addresses in the lease range to see which of them are free?

Comment: Your routing table tells your computer to send packages for another subnet to the router. In your subnet, ARP requests are made so that router and computer know who they are, and then the router in turn is going to do ARP requests to find out the MAC of the destination IP. Type `route -n` on Linux and `route something like /print` on windows to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the request is the router; it's sending the request, not a device outside the subnet.  ARP never crosses broadcast domain boundaries.  `10.162.3.172` is in the subnet, as far as the router is concerned, which means the subnet mask on the router is configured as `/22` or larger.

Answer (score 0):

Run wireshark on 10.162.3.172 and you will see who is looking for it .